# mysql fatal error, but i think i did every thing right

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

I used this code, but it shows fatal error and didn't give any information about error.

> Fatal error encountered during command execution.
>
> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException was unhandled by user code  Message=Fatal error encountered during command execution.  Source=MySql.Data  ErrorCode=-2147467259  Number=0  StackTrace:

Here is my code. I didn't show "connect" code because I call from outside.  It worked fine with previous query method.

```
public int insertRateToDB(string tableName, double rate, int cid, int subGroup)
{         
    sql = "UPDATE " + tableName + " SET rate = @rate, subGroup = @subGroup WHERE id = @cid;";
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql,connect);
    cmd.Prepare();
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@percent", rate);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@subGroup", subGroup);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cid", cid);
    int result = cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
    return result;
}
```

Comment: @rate is not defined as one of your parameters

Comment: Use @ rate iso @ percent

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need `@rate` parameter in the list not `@percent`

```
//cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@percent", rate);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rate", rate);
```

Comment: I changed to "@rate" right now, i executed nothing happened, IS something wrong with original sql?? @kaf

Comment: @riseres : `Call Prepare() method after setting the Commandtext and Parameters.` Or `try without it` Pls read this [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.prepare.aspx) link for more details